# Google App Engine Large Query to Display Rankings

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm looking for ideas on how to best accomplish the following:

I have 10,000 entities (Java objects) stored in Google App Engine's  datastore. 
The entities have many fields, one of which is "Sales" and represents a person's dollar amount sold.

I'm building a web page that displays two tables of sales rankings, ranked by their Sales amount. I'm using Java objects, Java Servlets, and JSPs for this site.

The first table will display a list of persons and their Sales ranking. The list of person's will be people will be a specific set of people who are on the team of the person logged into the site. For example, Julie, the manager of a store logs into the site, and has five sales associates. She will see a table that displays her five associates and their sales ranking out of all people in the datastore. For example:

Rank, Name, Sales
23, Alea Goodmanson, $1,875
37, Tom Jones, $1,550
77, Jasmine Johnson, $1,325
283, Chris Mowles, $1,100
643, Nancy Klipper, $650

The page will also display a second table showing everyone ranked 1-250 in a table below. I will provide links for the viewer to move forward and backward between the full list of results, 250 records at a time. For example, "Previous 250" and "Next 250" links will be available. I will also have links to jump to a specific range of records like "1,250-1,500" or "1,750-2,000" all the way up to the max in the list.

I need to display more than just the "Sales" data point on the web page. I will also be displaying a dozen other fields from the objects retrieved. So I need the full objects returned from the datastore.

The datastore is updated nightly with new data, but not updated during the day when people will be viewing the page.

What is the most efficient way to determine the rankings of the specific associates in the top table?

In order to determine any person's ranking, I need to query for all records, sorted by Sales, and find where the specific people fall in that order.

What queries should I execute? What should I consider placing in a cache? I'd like to avoid having to query for all records each time I need to determine the ranking of a subset of persons.

Should I query for all person IDs, sorted by Sales, then loop through the results and if one of the person IDs matches, save the index of the loop as that person's rank? Then issue an additional query for the first 250 full objects? I'd also have to query for the full objects of the specific people for the top table.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to retrieve a sorted list top scorers...  Fortunately someone has built it already.

[Java implementation](http://toolongdidntread.com/google-app-engine/using-googles-datastore-to-implement-a-ranked-scoreboard/)

[Python implementation](https://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-ranklist/)